# The sum of two closed subsets of $\mathbb R$ is not a closed set. What is wrong with the following argument?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two closed subsets of $\mathbb R$. Let us define $Z=X+Y=\{x+y~|~x\in X,y\in Y\}$

Since, $X$ is closed, $\forall~ x \in X, \exists$ a sequence in  $ X:\{x_n\}$ that converges to $x$.

Similarily $\forall~ y \in Y, \exists$ a sequence in  $ Y:\{y_n\}$ that converges to $y$.

Consider a point $ z=x+y \in X+Y$. Then, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$|z-(x_n+y_n)| = |(x-x_n)+(y-y_n)| \le |x-x_n|+|y-y_n| \le \epsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$

$\implies \forall z \in X+Y, \exists$ a sequence $\in X+Y$ which converges to $z \implies X+Y $ is closed.

> What could be the error in this argument? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It’s trivial that if $z\in X+Y$, then there is a sequence in $X+Y$ converging to $z$: the constant sequence $\langle z,z,z,\ldots\rangle$ does the trick. To show that $X+Y$ is closed, you must prove the converse: if $z\in\Bbb R$, and there is a sequence $\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to $z$, then $z\in X+Y$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much,

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with the argument is that it doesn't use a correct definition of "closed". You seem to be using "closed" to mean the following:

> A set $X$ is closed if for every point $x\in X$, there is some sequence in $X$ converging to $x$.

This is not what closed means - in fact *every* set satisfies this because the sequence $x,\,x,\,x,\,\ldots$ always converges to $x$. Rather, a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ is defined as follows:

> A set $X$ is closed if for every sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots,\in X$ that converges to some $x$ in $\mathbb R$, we have $x\in X$.

That is: if a sequence in a closed set converges, it converges in the closed set.

Therefore, to show that $X+Y$ is closed, you would have to start your argument as:

> Let $z_1,z_2,\ldots$ be a sequence in $X+Y$ that converges to some $z\in \mathbb R$. We wish to show $z\in X+Y$.

You would probably proceed by saying:

> Since each $z_i$ is in $X+Y$, we can come up with two sequences $x_1,x_2,\ldots\in X$ and $y_1,y_2,\ldots\in Y$ such that $x_i+y_i=z_i$.

You would, however, then be stuck: if you want to use that $X$ or $Y$ are closed, you would need to show that the sequences $x_i$ and $y_i$ have limits in $\mathbb R$ which does not follow from what the fact that the sum of these sequences has a limit - in fact, these sequences don't even need to be bounded!

The statement turns out to be false - a good way to get at a counterexample is to set $X=\mathbb Z$ and then see if you can use the fact that open intervals are unions of closed ones to somehow make $Y$ a "pile" of closed intervals whose translates stack into open ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a query please from the latter part of the answer. Since, $x_i+y_i$ is any sequence in $X+Y$ and $x_i$ must converge in $X$;  likewise, $y_i$ must converge in $Y$. Shouldn't their sums also converge in $X+Y$?

Comment: $x_i \rightarrow x_0, y_i \rightarrow y_0$ then $x_i +y_i \rightarrow x_0+y_0 \in X+Y$. Could you please explain?

Comment: @MathMan If you knew that $x_i$ and $y_i$ converged in $\mathbb R$, that would follow - but you don't. It could be that $x_n = n + 1/n$ and $y_n = -n$ for instance - their sum converges to $0$, but neither sequence converges. You don't get any control over $x_i$ and $y_i$ except for their sum - so you can't prevent a case like this where there are no limits to speak of.

Comment: Aah i get it now. In a closed set, it is not necessary that every sequence be convergent. But every point has a sequence which converges to that point. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MathMan Not quite - the first bit is right, not every sequences needs to be convergent. And it is also true that every point has a sequence convergent to it, but this is not relevant to closedness. The point is that "closed" means "closed under limits" - i.e. if a sequence in a closed set has a limit in $\mathbb R$ that limit must be in the set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it .